# Cancel out background:#fff without cancelling out background-image

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

[This Wordpress front page](http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/) uses a child theme.

The parent theme contains CSS:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}
```

This front page uses CSS:

```
body.home {
    background-image: url(http://www.fleeceitout.com/images/field.2.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

However, the `background-image` rule is being overridden by the `background` rule (I believe), and hence, the `body` of the page does not have a background image.

What CSS do I use to eliminate the `background: #fff;` rule, so that the `body` contains a background image?

Comment: There should be **no override since `body` is less specific than `body.home`**, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Please include enough code in the question to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the background-image rule is being overridden by the background rule (I believe), and hence, the body of the page does not have a background image.

You are wrong.

`body` is less specific than `body.home` so would get applied first and overridden by `body.home`.

Even if that wasn't the case, the `!important` rule would case `background-image` to be applied last.

Your problem is that `http://www.fleeceitout.com/images/field.2.jpg` leads to a server that is refusing connections.

---

If I replace the URL with one that works, you have a second problem (although not one that can be reproduced with the code in your question).

The `body` element is completely covered up by the `div#fullPage` element, which has a white background colour. You would have to set that to transparent in order to see the body's background through it.

Comment: Actually, it redirects to http://placekitten.com/152/150. My Chrome does not refuse the connection.